# How does CamScanner app auto detects any paper-sheet or any card ? How do I implement the same in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to figure out how does CamScanner app autodetect a card or paper in an Image and produces a scan like copy of it ?? Can it be implemented in JavaScript using HTML5 Canvas ??

My main concern is to extract that detected card or paper from the image for further processing, according to the need of my project.

Thanks in advance..
Any solution in JavaScript will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

This [solution](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/) works well in most cases. It is in Python, but you can easily adapt it to JavaScript since it is OpenCV. There is the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d10/tutorial_js_root.html) to use it and if you use node I recommend [opencv4nodejs](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/).

The main idea is find edges with Canny detector. After that you use the function to findContours from OpenCV and you need to search the largest contour with 4 edges (we expect that papers have a rectangular shape). The main issues usually are if there is noise in the background and to find contours white on white. Some filters before the Canny detector and changing the parameters can help in your solution.